# escaping a character included in a conceal command vimscript

Tags: vimscript, gvim, help-system

I'm playing with conceal in help files to highlight / colour specific text strings which was working fine until I added the :print: example below.

[image: conceal example]

Using this concealed all the `:` as expected so I tried to escape the `:` around the word print

```
 :%s/[^[:print:]]//g :
```

The original conceal statement was

```
syntax match myIgnoreHc /[:#]|[#:]/ contained conceal -Oopswrong original
syn match myhelpCommentHc       "[:#]\s.\{-}\s[:#]\s" contains=myIgnoreHc
```

I changed the match to

```
syntax match myIgnoreHc /[:#]\s\S\|\S\s[#:]/ contained conceal
```

which worked if I wrote the `:print:` as `: :print :` however I'd prefer to escape or tell the parser to ignore the match in certain situations eg `::` or `##` as the `:print :` isn't what I was after :).

Any suggestions?